# Regular Expression in C# allow white space in start until we type a character

Tags: c#, regex

hi i am trying to avoid having space in a input field using regular expressions in `c#` and if a user type a space show an error message and invalidate the field.
 But so far i have no luck as if i type `" "` empty spaces like these as much as i want but the regular expression is not  invalidate the field as soon as i type a character it invalidate the field and show the error message. i tried a lot of expressions like these:
`^[^\\s]+([A-Z0-9]+[^\\s]+)*$` 
`^\b[A-Z0-9]*\b$`
`^[A-Z0-9]*$`
`^[^\\s][A-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: Why compicate things. Why not call `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`.

Comment: It would be nice that you show several examples of *valid* **and** *invalid* strings .

Comment: how about a `\t` tab? do you allow this?

Comment: actually i am working with mvc and by adding regex in viewmodel help me validate fields on client site instead to validate on post that is why i am not using IsNullOrWhiteSpace()

Comment: valid string should be like `ASCADF123` means any letter in capital with numbers no lowercase letters and spaces

Comment: @MongZhu no it should not suppose to allow that

Comment: I hate web sites that do this. If spaces aren't allowed, can't you just trim the values afterwards?

Comment: well @stuartd it is a requirement not my wish for doing so

Answer (score 0):

to forbid spaces :

```
 ^[\S]*$
```

or

```
 ^[\S]+$
```

if you need at least one character.

To only allow for A-Z and 0-9, with at least one character :

```
 ^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. replaced `^\s` by `\S` , also I am not sure you are supposed to double the `\\`. Also other alternative to allow only for A-Z and 0-9.

Comment: ok i tried the 0 or many version of `^[A-Z0-9]+$` like `^[A-Z0-9]*$` but it did not seems to work let me check it again

Comment: @jazzb How are you using your regexp ?

Comment: same as expected it allow white spaces in start until i enter a character

Comment: i am using it in a viewmodel using RegularExpression annotation like this 
`[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FormViewModel), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldIsInvalid")]`

Comment: is it suppose to do something with it

Comment: The problem may be that , when you just enter spaces, the value is still considered empty and no validation is performed, except if the field is required. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx . You should make it required, or simply test for String.IsNullOrWhitespace on the backend, if you want to keep field optional, but reject any 'spaces only' input.

Comment: ok so is it a bug in .net ? or problem with regular expressions

Comment: @jazzb could you try to add : `ValidateEmptyText = true `  ?

Comment: where should i suppose to add it

Comment: You can try `[^\s]+` (without the start and end markers) . If doesn't work, then I strongly suggest you to use a CustomValidator instead. In this custom validator, you can use a regexp, and you will be able to check for these starting spaces as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(string value)` method to check white space in your input and then try to apply regular expression for other validations.